# Multiple items from different List view Drag drop in WPF

Tags: wpf, listview, drag

In a wpf application I have multiple ListViews. In one work flow, I have to select multiple items from different list views and drag and drop all the items to another control.

Drag Multiple items from a single list view is implemented as below. Can anyone please suggest if there is a possibility to drag multiple items from several different list views at a time?

XAML:

```
<ItemsControl  Name="groupsTab" ItemsSource="{Binding Stores}" Margin="0,0,10,10" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate >
        <DataTemplate>
            <GroupBox Name="groupsGroupBox" AllowDrop="True"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
      ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True" Margin="0,0,10,10">
                <GroupBox.Header>
                    <TextBlock   Text="{Binding StoreName}" FontWeight="Bold" PreviewMouseDown="BeatHeaderClick"  />
                </GroupBox.Header>
                <GroupBox.Content>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Branches}" Height="{Binding Path=GridHeight}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <WrapPanel IsItemsHost='True'/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <GroupBox  BorderThickness="1" Width="190" Visibility="{Binding Visibility}" BorderBrush="Black">
                                    <GroupBox.Header>
                                        <TextBlock   FontWeight="Bold" MaxWidth="160" Drop="ControlItem_Drop" MouseLeftButtonDown="ControlItem_PreviewMouseMove"
                                        Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AllowDrop="True"
                                        Foreground="{Binding Foreground}" Background="{Binding Background}">                                                                    
                                        </TextBlock>
                                    </GroupBox.Header>
                                    <ListView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource myListviewStyle}" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding Visibility}" SelectionChanged="LstView_SelectionChanged"
                           Width="180" MinHeight="30" SelectionMode="Extended"
                           ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                           ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Margin="0,0,0,0" BorderThickness="0"
                           MouseWheel="OnMouseWheelChanged" AllowDrop="True" Drop="TransferUnitToDiffStation" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="ListView_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
                            
                                              >
                                        <ListView.ItemsSource>
                                            <cad:ShapedCollection Source="{Binding Path=StaffDetails}" Where="IsVisible == true"/>
                                        </ListView.ItemsSource>
                                        <ListView.View>
                                            <GridView  ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridHeaderStyle}">
                                                <GridViewColumn  Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"></GridViewColumn>
                                                <GridViewColumn Width="35" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Gender}"></GridViewColumn>
                                                <GridViewColumn Width="35" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}"></GridViewColumn>
                                            </GridView>
                                        </ListView.View>
                                    </ListView>
                                </GroupBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </GroupBox.Content>
            </GroupBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

xaml.cs:

```
private void ListView_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(sender as DependencyObject, storeData, DragDropEffects.All);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.PrintError("Exception is thrown in ListView_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown() " + ex.Message + "\n Error Details " + ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```